# MVC4 - Controller Scaffolding, Custom Data context class issue: Unable to retrieve metadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datacontext, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

When I try to create a controller by scaffolding, I get the following error:

Unable to retrieve metadata for 'TurkUp.Models.Admin.CreateCourseViewModel'. Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
The mapping of CLR type EDM is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Coursework'.

Here is the code for the model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TorkUp.Models.Admin
{
    public class CreateCourseViewModel
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The custom data context class:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using TorkUp.ClassLibrary;
using TorkUp.ClassLibrary.Admin;
using TorkUp.ClassLibrary.User;

namespace TorkUp.Infrastructure
{
    public class UniversityDb : DbContext, IUniversityDataSource
    {
        public UniversityDb() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

        // Admin data
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Coursework> Courseworks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        // User data
        public DbSet<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }


        // Admin data
        IQueryable<Course> IUniversityDataSource.Courses { get { return Courses; } }

        IQueryable<Class> IUniversityDataSource.Classes { get { return Classes; } }

        IQueryable<Coursework> IUniversityDataSource.Courseworks { get { return Courseworks; } }

        IQueryable<Student> IUniversityDataSource.Students { get { return Students; } }

        // User data
        IQueryable<Assignment> IUniversityDataSource.Assignments { get { return Assignments; } }
        IQueryable<Task> IUniversityDataSource.Tasks { get { return Tasks; } }

        // Save to database
        void IUniversityDataSource.Save() { SaveChanges(); }
    }
}
```

And the class for the course:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TorkUp.ClassLibrary.Admin
{
    public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Coursework> Courseworks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code of your models and how do you create your context?

Comment: @lnanikian: Please check the updates in the post :)

Comment: And the Coursework model??  Have you got two different Coursework models, one in the TorkUp.ClassLibrary.Admin namespace and another in the TorkUp.ClassLibrary.User namespace?

Comment: @BrendanGreen: 
No I don't have any Coursework class in TorkUp.ClassLibrary.User.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error, it is because in you `DbContext`:

```
   // Admin data
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Coursework> Courseworks { get; set; } //you use here Coursework class to create a DbSet. But when you scaffold you use CreateCourseViewModel.
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

If you want to use `CreateCourseViewModel`, then you have to change this line above. But I think as you put `ViewModel` suffix the purpose of `CreatecourseViewModel` is to wrap another classes for displaying in the view.

Comment: Do you mean that the line should look like:
    public DbSet<CreateCourseViewModel> Courses { get; set; }

Comment: Depending of your design. You can also scaffold `CourseWork` instead of `createcourseviewmodel`.

Comment: That is actually a good idea, I did not think of it. Thank you @lnanikian.
To apply this I will have to rework my code but it will be okay :)